# Java Play 2.3 Match any route which starts with certain string

Tags: java, routes, playframework-2.0

is there a way to match only a part from a route.
I need a route definition which should match the following routes

/route

/route/part1
...

The part after "/route" is dynamic and variable. Every route which starts with "/route" should be matched.

My try:

```
GET     /route/<[a-z]+>             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/web", file="static.html")
```

Error: Action not found For request 'GET /route/home'

```
GET     /route/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/web", file="static.html")
```

Error: It is not allowed to specify a fixed or default value for parameter: 'file' extracted from the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename and move /public/web/static.html to /app/views/staticFile.scala.html
2. Change the route to

   ```
   GET  /route/*path    controllers.Application.staticFile(path: String)
   ```
3. Add the method to /app/controllers/Application.java

   ```
   public static Result staticFile(String path) {
       return ok(views.html.staticFile.render());
   }
   ```